# Show/hide in javascript when no html access

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```
  <div id="myid1">Text 1</div>
  <div id="myid2">Text 2</div>
  <div id="myid3">Text 3</div>
```

and I would hide all these elements by default. Then when I click on a link, I would like show all them at once. I looked for some solution in Javascript but it seem is not possible to declare multiple ID when using document.getElementById.

Precision: I seen many solution who suggest to use class instead ID. The problem is I work with an external application integrated in my site and I have access partially to html, but I can set javascript code inside a dedicated JS file.

Comment: do you have a option to wrap above code within an parent DIV? if that's the case then you can control your parent DIV within your JS File.

Comment: no unfortunately. The code is a bit messy and the parent div include some others element which don't need to be show/hide

Answer (score 2):

You could create a function that retrieves several elements by their `id`, and simply iterate over that collection of elements to hide or show them:

```
function getElementsByIds(idArray) {
    // initialise an array (over which we'll iterate, later)
    var elements = [];

    // if no arguments have been passed in, we quit here:
    if (!arguments) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        /* we're running a basic check to see if the first passed-argument
           is an array; if it is, we use it: */
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(arguments[0]) === '[object Array]') {
            idArray = idArray;
        }
        /* if a string has been passed-in (rather than an array), we
           make an array of those strings: */
        else if ('string' === typeof arguments[0]) {
            idArray = [].slice.call(arguments);
        }

        // here we iterate over the array:
        for (var i = 0, len = idArray.length; i < len; i++) {

            // we test to see if we can retrieve an element by the id:
            if (document.getElementById(idArray[i])) {
                /* if we can, we add that found element to the array
                   we initialised earlier: */
                elements.push(document.getElementById(idArray[i]));
            }
        }
    }
    // returning the elements:
    return elements;
}

// here we toggle the display of the elements (between 'none' and 'block':
function toggle (elems) {
    // iterating over each element in the passed-in array:
    for (var i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++) {
        /* if the current display is (exactly) 'none', we change to 'block'
           otherwise we change it to 'none': */
        elems[i].style.display = elems[i].style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
}

function hide (nodes) {
    // iterating over the passed-in array of nodes
    for (var i = 0, len = nodes.length; i < len; i++) {
        // setting each of their display properties to 'none':
        nodes[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}

// getting the elements:
var relevantElements = getElementsByIds('myid1','myid2','myid3'),
    toggleButton = document.getElementById('buttonThatTogglesVisibilityId');

// binding the click-handling functionality of the button:
toggleButton.onclick = function(){
    toggle (relevantElements);
};

// initially hiding the elements:
hide (relevantElements);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RPm9s/3/).

References:

- [`arguments` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments).
- [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
- [`Array.protoype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- [`Object.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString).
- [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Comment: this could work but how to do for hide all text by default and show them only when the button is clicked ? I tried to play by inverting none/block in your Fiddle but without success (sorry I'm a poor newbie)

Comment: I tested and that work on your fiddle but is not working at my side. Text is not hidden and when I click on button I'm redirected to another page of my site. I think I have some conflict somewhere. I must investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Three options (at least):

1) Wrap them all in a parent container if this is an option. Then you can just target that, rather than the individual elements.

```
document.getElementById('#my_container').style.display = 'block';
```

2) Use a library like jQuery to target multiple IDs:

```
$('#myid1, #myid2, #myid3').show();
```

3) Use some ECMA5 magic, but it won't work in old browsers.

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#myid1, #myid2, #myid3'), function(el) {
    el.style.display = 'block'; //or whatever
});
```

Comment: by admitting I use your option2 (I don't know if I can use Jquery I must test), how will look the link code ?

Comment: `$('show-link-button').click(function(){ $('#myid1, #myid2, #myid3').show();} )`

Comment: I don't see how to use this code inside my html link

Answer (score 0):

If id="myid< increment-number >" then you can select these elements very easily.

Below code will select all elements that  START WITH "myid".

```
$("div[id^='myid']").each(function (i, el) {
    //do what ever you want here
}
```

See jquery doc 
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/